# I get a "Warning" after adding the line APT_AUTOGEN="yes" to /etc/default/rkhunter with gedit

Tags: gnome-terminal, gedit, rkhunter

The warning is the following: "(gedit:38572): Tepl-WARNING **: 09:45:20.468: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata."

What should I do? Is this normal?

This is what I was doing:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckWnk.jpg)

How should I proceed to properly install rkhunter?

Comment: I put the following command in the terminal "sudo -H gedit /etc/default/rkhunter" using "-H" as you suggested and I got essentially the same warning: (gedit:40695): Tepl-WARNING **: 10:32:29.476: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.

Comment: I also get the same error with or without -H when using gedit. This is after upgrading to 20.04. It did not happen on 19.10.